Problem with updating value in a Pointer location
The  problem statement of Hackerrank Pointers question for C++ is to update two Pointers value, one with the sum and other with the difference using a function named update. The solution code is :-

#include <stdio.h>

void update (int *a,int *b) {
    int sum = *a + *b;
    int subtract;
    if (*a > *b)
    {
         subtract = *a - *b;
    }  
    else
    {
        subtract = *b - *a;
    }
    *a = sum;
    *b = subtract;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

    return 0;
}

Sample input in this case :- 4 5
Sample output in this case :- 9 1
However if i try to simplify it a bit like :-
#include <stdio.h>

void update(int *a , int *b) {
    *a = *a + *b;
    # Or even if i use :- *b = *a - *b > 0 ? *a - *b : *b - *a; to calculate *b
    int subtract;
    if (*a > *b)
    {
         subtract = *a - *b;
    }  
    else
    {
        subtract = *b - *a;
    }
    
    *b = subtract;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

    return 0;
}

This code ends up updating the sum i.e. *a but instead of  updating *b, it just assigns the value of whatever i wrote first to *b
Sample input in this case :- 4 5
Sample output in this case :- 9 4
Can anyone please tell me why this is happening?
I am using VSCode to execute my programs.
I have tried looking at various resources to again understand the basic definitions but i am not able to figure this out.

*a = *a + *b; -- You are updating what a points to, and then using this updated value from there.  You are not doing this in the code that works, i.e -- int sum = *a + *b; -- I have tried looking at various resources to again understand the basic definitions but i am not able to figure this out. -- The only resource you need is to carefully follow your program, step by step.

This is C, not C++.

"Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? ..." What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems
